# RNNs - How to min-max scaling out-of-sample for test case

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to predict Bitcoin price by RNNs with Tensorflow.

My model is quite simple RNNs with LSTM :

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh)
outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
predict = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], num_output,
                                            activation_fn=None)  # use last cell's output
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(predict - Y))  # MSE
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)'
```

I have 35000 hourly Bitcoin price data.

I split it to train dataset(older data) and test dataset(newer data).

Before training I tried to Min-Max Scaling so as to all train data is scaled between 0 to 1.

```
# to avoid divide by zero, add noise
data = (data - np.min(np.abs(data), axis=0)) / (
            np.max(np.abs(data), axis=0) - np.min(np.abs(data), axis=0) + 1e-8)
```

However, since Bitcoin price increase dramatically last year(which is under test dataset), my model cannot predict at all for test dataset.

[image: Sad prediction result. Image from here]

(Image from [here](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2017/07/08/predict-stock-prices-using-RNN-part-1.html))

I tried another two ways :

1. Just fix max price data
   I just fix maximum price such as 35,000$.

   ```
   # to avoid divide by zero, add noise
   data = (data - np.min(np.abs(data), axis=0)) / (
               35000 - np.min(np.abs(data), axis=0) + 1e-8)
   ```

   It works well and prediction result is fine. However, I'm feeling this is 
   quite unsmart way - what if Bitcoin rise over 35,000$?
2. Predict by increase/decrease rate

   ```
   data = data[1:] / data[:len(data) - 1]
   ```

   I modified whole data such as above so as to data will be like (price for 
   tomorrow) / (price for today).

   In this way, whole data is just between 0.8 ~ 1.2 so it doesn't need any 
   min-max scaling.

   However, this way fails since it is not trained well.

Is there any better way for this problem?